# Floating accuracy in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, correlation, floating-accuracy

when I apply `pd.rolling_corr` on some data set, I find the correlation matrix generated has values like -1.0000000000074845. I know it is about floating accuracy, but I do not know the usual way to deal with it in practice? For example this value is less than -1 so I can not find the positions that have exact -1 value. Also the matrix won't pass the check that all values are between [-1,1].

Comment: These behaviors do not come from pandas. Look for details here: https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/floatingpoint.html You can try to use module `mpmath` for for real and complex floating-point arithmetic with arbitrary precision http://mpmath.org/doc/current/basics.html